# How can I create installer with .net

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-installer, monogame

I have a game written in MonoGame in VS2012. How can I create setup file witch will also install .net framework if user doesn't have it?

Comment: What version of .NET do you need to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no setup projects in VS 2012, unless you get the InstallShield LE add-in. VS 2010 had setup projects; VS 2013 supports the return of installer projects as an add-in. Therefore you may be stuck looking for a 3rd party solution, like InstallShield LE or any other number of other tools that can build setups and have a VS IDE add-in support (such as WiX). List of tools here:

http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/authoring.htm

If you are keen on VS setup projects and want a simple tool that does the basics without you needing to learn too much, moving to VS 2013 and using the installer projects add-in would probably suit you.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d

Comment: Will it install required .net framework automaticaly?

Comment: Possibly. .NET is complicated.  It depends on what version you need and what OS(s) you are targeting.  Some can be installed via an EXE, others via a DISM command.  For the DISM, some are automatically included in the install.win  and others require a download to Windows Update.  It gets complicated.

Comment: I want to install it only on Windows

Comment: Chris's "what OS" means which version of Windows. Most have some version of.NET, pre-installed, some a redistributable, some don't, some need it activating as feature.